# Update users location even when app is terminated

Tags: iphone, swift

Hi I'm new to iPhone app development. I need to update users location even when app is terminated or killed by users. Is it possible in swift code?

Comment: Please check this one -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503990/ios-running-background-task-for-update-user-location-using-swift

Comment: You must remind/notify user NOT to kill app

Answer (score 0):

You can track the user's location while your app is still active in the background if you are registered for background updates, which you can find out how to do [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW9). However you **can not** track a user once they have quit your application.