# Background Task works on Simulator only

Tags: ios, swift, timer, background-process, uilocalnotification

#### Background

I have created a sample timer app that counts from a specific value down to zero. A label displays how much time is left.

Every time the `NSTimer` (1s interval) calls `countDownSecs()` it prints how many seconds are left and executes `println("countDownSecs()")`. When the countdown has reached `0` seconds it sends a local push notification. 
When running in the **simulator** that **works** and even for like 5 minutes it stays in the background and continuously prints the seconds left and `countDownSecs()`. 
On the other hand, when running on an actual device (iPhone 4S, iOS 8.1.3 and iOS 8.3) it stops immediately when entering the background. (It worked before on the one w/ iOS 8.3. I thought it might be because the iPhone 4S can not handle that but the iPhone 4S simulator works perfectly fine.)

#### Code

In the `AppDelegate`'s `applicationDidEnterBackground()` I have the following code for the `UILocalNotification`:

```
var alarmTime: NSDate = NSDate()
var app: UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
var notifyAlarm: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()

//counterAll contains the total amount of seconds        
alarmTime.dateByAddingTimeInterval(NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate())
notifyAlarm.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: counterAll)
notifyAlarm.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
notifyAlarm.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit(0)
notifyAlarm.soundName = "Time's Up.m4a"
notifyAlarm.alertBody = "Time's Up! - Your timer has ended."
app.scheduleLocalNotification(notifyAlarm)
```

#### Question

Can I change anything to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Isn't it alarmTime suppose to be the fireDate?

Comment: `alarmTime ` always was 0 so I used the `NSTimeInterval` `counterAll`. The notification works perfectly.

Comment: did you registerUserNotificationSettings?

Comment: Yes, and again, as I said the notification works fine.

Comment: I think you should use  NSTimer(fireDate:) instead of using the countdown

Comment: you will need to add the timer for mainRunLoop NSRunLoopCommonModes

Comment: Your timer it is getting killed

Comment: try adding this line after setting your timer NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(yourTimer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)

Comment: I have that line implemented already. :/

Comment: try setting your notification before applicationDidEnterBackground maybe applicationWillResignActive

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79584/discussion-between-linus-g-and-leo-dabus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `NSTimer` **won't work** in the background in *actual* devices. It works in **simulators only**. However, you can execute background tasks with `UIApplication`s method `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`, however Apple has set a hard limit for background execution (180 seconds only if I remember correctly).

It is advisable to use `UILocalNotification`s instead of background tasks.

Comment: First, thanks for taking your time. Secondly, I don't believe this is true. As I wrote, it worked on an actual advice but I can not remember what was different / when that stopped working and can not restore it to that version. 
I also wrote that I am using `UILocalNotification`s already which made it work in first place.

Comment: Maybe you used a background task previously? Because any code should stop when the app entered background mode.

Comment: No idea how background tasking works. When I implemented the `UILocalNotification` in the `applicationDidEnterBackground()` it began to work. Also note that even when I quit the app completely (from multitasking) the notification still works.

Comment: Yes, `UILocalNotification`s work even when the application is closed because they're not background tasks.

Comment: Here's from Apple developer docs for background execution:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html